# Given $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_1-P_2$ are projections, show that $R_{P_2} \subseteq R_{P_1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Let $P_1$, $P_2$ be projections such that $P_1-P_2$ is a projection.

Show that $R_{P_2} \subseteq R_{P_1}$, where $R_{P_1}$ and $R_{P_2}$ are the ranges of $P_1$ and $P_2$, respectively.

My idea so far is that since $P_1-P_2$ is a projection, then we have:

$\begin{align}(P_1-P_2)^2&=P_1-P_2\\
P_1^2-P_1P_2-P_2P_1+P_2^2&=P_1-P_2\\
P_1-P_1P_2-P_2P_1+P_2&=P_1-P_2\\
2P_2-P_1P_2-P_2P_1&=0\end{align}$

From here, we could suppose that $x\in R_{P_2}$, then $P_2x=x$ (projection restricted to its own range), and then:

$\begin{align}2P_2x-P_1P_2x-P_2P_1x&=0\end{align}\dots$

After this last line, I tried arranging things in a few different ways but I couldn't quite see anything (although it might be staring me right in the face).  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $2P_2=P_1P_2+P_2P_1 \ (*)$, we do the following:

1/ multiply by $P_1$ to the left we have $2P_1P_2=P_1P_2+P_1P_2P_1$ or
$$P_1P_2=P_1P_2P_1$$

2/ multiply by $P_1$ to the right we have $2P_2P_1=P_1P_2P_1+P_2P_1$ or
$$P_2P_1=P_1P_2P_1$$

Compare what we have in $1/, 2/$ and $(*)$, we get $P_1P_2=P_1P_2P_1=P_2P_1$. Therefore, $(*)$ becomes $$P_2=P_1P_2$$

It follows that $R_{P_2} \subseteq R_{P_1}$.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes sense because in general $R_{ST} \subset R_S$.  But having $P_2 = P_1P_2$ is a little disconcerting at first glance.  I guess this just means that $P_1$ is the identity or $P_2$ is the zero map?

Comment: No, in general, it doesn't imply anyone of them. Just take $P_1,P_2$ in simplest form: diagonal matrices with $0,1$ in the diagonals, and $P_1$ has more $1$'s than $P_2$.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  And those are still projections as well.  Thanks again.